# How can I keep a word from a text and put it in a linked list?

Tags: c++

At this project I'm trying to keep every word from a text that user enters. Then, every word will be sent to a linked list.

my problems :

1. First word will be sent but when after first word, all words will be appended in kelime also?
2. In C++ , when we take a text from user, it's trimming first and end spaces, so I couldn't read the last word. I tried to open condition with (`metin[i]!=' ' || metin[i] != '\0'`) but it didnt work.

Code:

```
void metin(){
    string metin;
    string kelime;

    getline(cin, metin);
    metin += ' ';

    if (metin == ""){
        cout << "Bir metin girmediniz\n" << "Tekrar girmek ister misiniz?\n" << "Y - N\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < metin.length(); i++){
        if (metin[i] != ' '){
            kelime +=  metin[i];
        }
        else cout << kelime << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your mistake is very simple: you forgot the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming, which is "your computer will always do exactly what you tell your computer to do, instead of what you want it to do". After printing each word, you obviously want to remove it from `kelime`, so it is now empty, and can start collecting the letters from the next word. But you never told your computer that it should do that, so your computer simply continues to add the letters from the next word to `kelime`, which still has the old word in it. So to fix this, simply tell your computer exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: `metin == ""` will never be `true`, since you always add `' '` to `metin`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i tried it but it didnt work. it returned me full of empty words.

Comment: @ChrisMM wow! thanks , i didnt see it.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a useful problem description. Especially when used to describe the results from some unclear code changes that are not even shown.